# php config for ImpressPages

Tags: php, config, impresspages

Please tell us witch best php config for ImpressPages

php version 5.5

you can find attached to this post.

[image: php 5.5 config]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off magic quotes. The rest looks good.